# Why this error come FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Tags: java, android

I'm developing a application to view list view.But There is runtime error
This is my code. There are codes files and exception error that I got in run time.

```
package com.example.official2.xoxo.activity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.official2.xoxo.R;
import com.example.official2.xoxo.app.Config;

import com.example.official2.xoxo.helper.JSONParser;
import com.example.official2.xoxo.helper.JsonWebToken;
import com.example.official2.xoxo.helper.SQLiteHandler;
import com.example.official2.xoxo.helper.ServiceHandler;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
public class Products extends AppCompatActivity{

private String TAG = Products.class.getSimpleName();
//Call the config class to get the url
public Config con = new Config();
private String url_details = con.getAllProducts();

//ArrayOption-->Array Adapter--> ListView
//List View:(Views: productlist.xml)
private ListView lv;
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
   // CustomListAdapter adapter;
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    ServiceHandler sh;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;
// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "http://uat.fxhello.com/api/shop/products";
JsonWebToken jsonWebToken;
//JSON NODE NAMES
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "payload";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "product_name";
private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
private static final String TAG_PIC = "profileimage";

private SQLiteHandler db;
JSONArray contacts = null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_products);
    productList = new ArrayList<>();

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewProducts);

    jsonWebToken = new JsonWebToken();
   // String tok = jsonWebToken.getDefaults(getContext());
    String tok = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOjE3MDcsImlzcyI6Imh0dHA6XC9cL3VhdC5meGhlbGxvLmNvbVwvYXBpXC9hdXRoZW50aWNhdGUiLCJpYXQiOjE0ODIzNDMzMDMsImV4cCI6MTQ4MjQyOTcwMywibmJmIjoxNDgyMzQzMzAzLCJqdGkiOiI3NGQ5ZGIwNTA3NDc2NDAwNzc2MmYzODJiNGQxZmU4MCJ9.LF2Q8KUD7hoFjBJ4fsNjYS8rCzCevsZ4g0jukBK0lj0";
    Log.d("Responsetoken", tok);

    new Getproduct().execute();

    //populateListView();
}
/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 */
private class Getproduct extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {
    private JSONObject json;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
       // pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Products.this);
        //pDialog.setMessage("Loading Contacts. Please wait...");
        //pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        //pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        //pDialog.show();
    }

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

        String userID = args[0];
        sh = new ServiceHandler(userID);

        String jsondata = sh.makeServiceCall(url_details, ServiceHandler.POST, null);
        // JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_details,"GET");
        System.out.println("jsondata" + jsondata);
        if (jsondata != null)
            Log.d("Create Response", jsondata);
        else {

            Toast.makeText(Products.this.getApplicationContext(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(jsondata);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject s) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
       // pDialog.dismiss();

        System.out.println(productList);

        try {

            JSONArray products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT);

            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                //Storing each json item in a variable
                String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String price = c.getString(TAG_PRICE);
                // String image = c.getString(TAG_PIC);
                //tmp hash map for single contact
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                //adding each child node to HashMap => value
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_PRICE, price);
                // map.put(TAG_PIC,image);
                productList.add(map);
                // adding contact to contact list
                productList.add(map);

                // Dismiss the progress dialog
                //if (pDialog.isShowing())
                  //  pDialog.dismiss();

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        Products.this, productList,
                        R.layout.productlist, new String[]{TAG_ID, TAG_NAME,
                        TAG_PRICE}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                        R.id.email, R.id.mobile});

                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        } catch (final JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }
    }
}

}
```

ServiceHandler class file. I used this code to get data to products from service handler

```
package com.example.official2.xoxo.helper;

import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Official 2 on 12/19/2016.
 */
public class ServiceHandler {

static InputStream is = null;
static String response = null;
public final static int GET = 1;
public final static int POST = 2;
private  String token;
private String refresh_url = "application/vnd.fxhello.v1+json";

public ServiceHandler() {

}

public ServiceHandler(String token) {
    this.token = token;
}

/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * */
/**
 * Making service call
 * @url - url to make request
 * @method - http request method
 * @params - http request params
 * */
public String makeServiceCall(String url, int method,
                              List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {

        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            String tok = token;
            Log.d("Responsetoken", tok);
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            httpGet.setHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+tok);
            httpGet.setHeader("Accept", refresh_url);
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        response = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error: " + e.toString());
    }

    return response;

}

public String makeADDCall(String url, int method,


                          List<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {

        // http client
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;

        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == POST) {
            String tok = token;
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post params
            if (params != null) {
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                httpPost.setHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+tok);
                httpPost.setHeader("Accept", refresh_url);
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        } else if (method == GET) {
            // appending params to url
            String tok = token;
            Log.d("Responsetoken", tok);
            if (params != null) {
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils
                        .format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
            }
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            httpGet.setHeader("Authorization",tok);
            httpGet.setHeader("Accept", refresh_url);
            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        }
        httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        response = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error: " + e.toString());
    }

    return response;

}

   }
```

I  got this as error

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
 Process: com.example.official2.xoxo, PID: 30695
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:309)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
  Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
     at com.example.official2.xoxo.activity.Products$Getproduct.doInBackground(Products.java:97)
     at com.example.official2.xoxo.activity.Products$Getproduct.doInBackground(Products.java:95)
     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

This are the server side values---------------------------

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wDwM.jpg)

Comment: Read the stacktrace. It points to `String userID = args[0];` What value do you expect that to be?

Comment: it used to pass data from service handler class

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in Products.java, line 97

Comment: @Gayan again, "What value do you expect that to be?"

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I cannot understand the anwer

Comment: Actually from service handler i need to pass header values                      httpGet.setHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+tok);
                httpGet.setHeader("Accept", refresh_url);

Answer (score 0):

Your contacts JsonArray is null.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {}
```

Should be

```
    JSONArray products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT)
        for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {}
```

Comment: actually an empty array (can't be null because it is a varargs). However, you are right, when the OP fixes the first issue, they will realize that `contacts` is null as well

Comment: Yup @njzk2, btw nice catch. if issue is not resolved then please post code of makeServiceCall on your ServiceHandler class

Comment: I added it as a answer @rahul

Comment: Can you explain, from where you are sending parameter? String userID = args[0];

Comment: Actually from service handler i need to pass header values httpGet.setHeader("Authorization","Bearer "+tok); httpGet.setHeader("Accept", refresh_url);

Answer (score 0):

I think the Toast in doInBackground method is causing the problem ... because in this method you cannot communicate with UI thread... PreExecute and PostExecute methods can do.

Comment: ohh yes ... write contacts.length() -1 instead of contants.length() in for loop

Comment: welll ... every time i get into this type of situation ... i add logs at several positions in code ... that help me a lot ... you should give it a try ... print values which you are using as index and length of array ... that might help you

Answer (score 0):

Your stacktrace links to:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
     at com.example.official2.xoxo.activity.Products$Getproduct.doInBackground(Products.java:97)
     at com.example.official2.xoxo.activity.Products$Getproduct.doInBackground(Products.java:95)
```

Which corresponds with this line: `String userID = args[0];`

This line is an array, which explains ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

And it is due to this:

```
new Getproduct().execute();
```

You never pass any arguments in when you initialize getproduct, so the array index is 0 an as such causing the exception